# What would be the time complexity for a while loop that uses binary search for finding duplicates in a sorted list?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I was wondering what is the time complexity of the function **duplicate** would be because I was thinking it is **O(nlogn)** due to using the binary search algorithm and at the same time implementing a while loop to search through the left and right sides of the location of the first instance inside the array where the value was found to see if its duplicated inside the sorted array. I would like to know if its **O(logn)** because I was thinking that the while loop is not actually looping through all elements, just the ones nearby the value we are searching for to see if its duplicated. I would appreciate any advice in making it **O(logn)** if its not.

```
public class Problem2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int[] arrayA = {-1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 9, 10};
        
        int repeatedValue = 6;
        
        System.out.println(duplicates(arrayA, repeatedValue));
    }
    
    public static int duplicates(int[] a, int x){
        
        int counter = 0;                 //counter for duplicates.
        int index = binarySearch(a, x);  // index = 4 where x is.
        int leftIndex = index - 1;       // leftIndex = 3
        int rightIndex = index + 1;      // rightIndex = 5
        
        //Condition incase value does not exist.
        if(index == -1)
            return -1;
        
        //While loop to check left and right side of index for duplicates.
        while(a[leftIndex] == x || a[rightIndex] == x){
            
            if(a[leftIndex] == x){
                counter++;
                leftIndex--;
                
            }
            else if(a[rightIndex] == x){
                counter++;
                rightIndex++;
                
            }
           
        }
        
        //returning the counter plus one because we did not count the first instance
        //when it was searched.
        return counter + 1;
    }
    
    public static int binarySearch(int[] a, int x){
        
        int low = 0, high = a.length - 1;
        
        while(low <= high){
            
            int mid = (low + high) / 2;
            
            if(a[mid] < x)
                low = mid + 1;
            else if(a[mid] > x)
                high = mid - 1;
            else
                return mid;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I must be missing something here.  To do a binary search, the list has to be sorted.  If it's sorted, duplicates will be adjacent.  Why would you do anything other than iterating through the list and comparing each element to its predecessor, finding all duplicates in O(n) time?

Comment: Well the goal is to design a O(logn) algorithm for finding duplicates and counting the frequency in the sorted array, but before attempting that I tried to do it how I had it in my mind at first which was to use a binary search to find the index of the first instance of the value I want to check to see if its duplicated. Hence, once I had that index I used it as reference in the while loop to check both adjacent sides using leftIndex and rightIndex, which sounded great, but I realized it has it downfall when the number is on the edge due to out of bound. I saw recursion fix it, but new at it.

Comment: You can find occurrences of a particular value in O(log n) time, but to find all possible duplicates requires you to assess all values in the array.  There's no way I know of to process all n values in less than O(n) time. If you know a way, by all means please share it with me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `O(n*logn)` because you're *NOT* doing a linear search *FOR* every binary search: you're doing a linear search *AND* a binary search.

I's either `O(logn)` or `O(n)` depending on how many duplicates there are of your target number. Since `O(n)` is larger than `O(logn)`, your worst-case complexity is `O(n)`.

To say something more about your average-case complexity, we need to know what the average-case input looks like.

If on average the number of duplicates in a list of size `n` (that you actually search for) is lower than `logn`, you would have `O(logn)` average-case complexity.

**As for advice on how to make it `O(logn)`:**

To do a binary search, you are already doing a pre-computation step on your input, which is to sort the array.

Change the pre-computation step to not only sort the array, but also deduplicate the array and store the number of duplicates of each unique number in a separate array.

Then the search algorithm becomes:

1. Binary search for the right index of your target number
2. Return the number of duplicates for the number from the separate array with duplicate counts, using the index that you found in step 1

This only makes sense if you're searching for a lot of different target numbers on the same input data.